# repeating a character using printf and appending a newline at the end

Tags: sed, printf

In order to repeat a character N times, we could use `printf`. E.g to repeat `@` 20 times, we could use something like this:

```
N=20
printf '@%.0s' $(seq 1 $N)
```

output:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

However, there is no newline character at the end of that string. I've tried piping the output to `sed`:

```
printf '@%.0s' $(seq 1 $N) | sed '$s/$/\n/'
```

Is it possible to achieve the same result with a single `printf` (adding a newline character at the end of the output) without using sed?

Comment: add a line `printf '\n'`

Comment: What's the problem with using an additional command?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
printf %.1s @{1..20} $'\n'
```

the shell expands the braces first, this is called "Brace Expansion".
`@{1..20}` into `@1 @2 @3 ...` and so on
Then the first byte of each parameter will be output, including the last argument `$'\n'` consisting of one byte - the newline character

Comment: +1 but bear it deserves a mention that it is not portable. It will work in Bash and Ksh.

Comment: @Quasimodo, that would be ksh93, zsh, bash and recent versions of mksh. The `$'\n'` syntax comes from ksh93 and the `{1..20}` syntax from zsh. `%.1s` gets you the first *character* in zsh, and first *byte* in other POSIX-like shells, but that should make no difference as `@` is generally single-byte. Note that `printf` is not builtin in `mksh`, so that wouldn't scale to very large numbers of `@`.

Comment: such a clever solution.  thanks!

Answer (score 11):

With `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' ${(l[20][@])}
```

(using the `l` left-padding [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags). You could also use the `r`ight padding one here).

Of course, you don't have to use `printf`. You could also use `print` or `echo` here which do add a `\n` by default. (`printf '%s\n' "$string"` can be written `print -r -- "$string"` or `echo -E - "$string"` in `zsh`, though if `$string` doesn't contain backslashes and doesn't start with `-`, that can be simplified to `print "$string"`/`echo "$string"`).

If the end-goal is to display a list of strings padded to the width of the screen, you'd do:

```
$ lines=(short 'longer text' 'ｅｖｅｎ　ｌｏｎｇｅｒ')
$ print -rC1 -- ${(ml[$COLUMNS][@][ ])lines}
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ short
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ longer text
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ｅｖｅｎ　ｌｏｎｇｅｒ
$ print -rC1 -- ${(mr[$COLUMNS][@][ ])lines}
short @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
longer text @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
ｅｖｅｎ　ｌｏｎｇｅｒ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Where the `m` flag causes zsh to take into account the display width of each character (like for those double-width characters above (which your browser may not render with exactly double-width, but your terminal should)).

`print -rC1 --` is like `printf '%s\n'` or `print -rl --` to print one element per line except in the case where no arguments are passed to it (like when `lines=()`) in which case it prints nothing instead of an empty line).

Comment: https://brettterpstra.com/2015/02/20/shell-trick-printf-rules/

Comment: Why only zsh? , the OP doesn't state that.

Answer (score 2):

I use this in a script:
`printf '%150s\n' | tr ' ' '@'`

Comment: I've seen that in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oo_KrWjYuaY). But unfortunately, It's the same as mine, and it requires another command.

Comment: @Navaro It seems you wanted to get rid of `sed`, but `seq` was OK. Here it's `tr` instead of `sed`, but there is no `seq`. The answer still uses one process less than your example.

Comment: @Navaro OK, but for a fixed number your question is trivial (unless the number is too big). You just hardcode the string: `printf '@@@@…@@@\n'`. The question is useful when the number is not fixed, therefore the presence of `seq` in the example should count.

Comment: @Navaro So `seq` in the example cannot be trivially omitted. This means any solution that gets rid of `seq` (and can still work with a non-fixed number) saves you one process. Why is saving one process by getting rid of just `seq` (the answer) worse than saving one process by getting rid of just `sed` (your request)?

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have taken the tack of using the extensions to standard shell syntax that are available in specific shells such as the Korn, Z, and Bourne Again shells.
There is nothing wrong in doing so, but there is an alternative approach.

One can take advantage of the facts that (a) video terminals are not "dumb", and never really have been; and (b) nowadays, in the third decade of the 21st century, most video terminals and even their *emulators*, largely agree on understanding ECMA-48, rather than a control sequence system of their own.

ECMA-48, since its earliest days in the 1970s, has defined a control sequence REP, which is CSI, a parameter, and `b` as the final character.
This repeats the previous graphic character printed (amongst other things, which I won't go into here as we only care about graphic characters).

It has taken terminal *emulators* some time to catch up with real terminals.
Whereas the likes of the DEC VT5xx series in the 1990s understood REP, it is only within the last decade that it has become commonplace on terminal emulators.
XTerm was well ahead of most and has understood it since 1996, but libVTE and KDE Konsole didn't catch up until 2017 and 2018.

So as long as your real video terminal or terminal emulator understands something that was standardized in the 1970s, and you aren't using a paper terminal (which is vanishingly unlikely), printing `@` 20 times can be done with *no* shell-specific syntax, *no* command pipelines, *no* substitutions or stream editing, and just `printf`:

```
printf '@\033[%db\n' 19
```

This works with pretty much all shells, even the Debian Almquist shell.

You can check the termcap/terminfo database for the `repeat_char`/`rep` capability to determine whether a terminal type supports REP.
(The usual caveats apply: Some old real terminals respond to non-ECMA-48 control sequences, and `tput rp` is a better approach than `printf` in the general case, even though the non-ECMA-48 case is quite unlikely in practice; you must check the *correct* terminal type, that matches your terminal, not just *wrongly* assume "Oh, it's `xterm`."; and your terminfo/termcap database must be up-to-date.)

That said, it is surprising that the world that has `banner`, `figlet`, `boxes`, and `cowsay` didn't create and make widespread a simple utility that could emit various styles of horizontal rule in all these years.
Imagine:

```
hr -c @ -n 20
```

Comment: `tput rp` : `tput: unknown terminfo capability 'rp'`
 do you mean `tput rep`

Comment: That's a parenthetical, and I didn't want to go into it too deeply, because not all `tput`s being the same is quite a diversion.  `rp` is the termcap name.

Comment: Note that it doesn't appear to be supported by GNU screen.

Comment: Would be useful to explain that only prints **one** line, no matter how many characters.

Comment: It "only prints one line" in the same sense as every other answer here, in that it only prints a newline at the end.  Printing does wrap onto multiple lines.  Being as that is what the question asked for, and you don't see the need to explain it yourself in _your_ answer, that seems superfluous to explain.

Comment: It doesn't wrap in my tests. @JdeBP

Comment: This won't print as many characters as you tell it, at least not on my system (`terminator` terminal and `bash`). It will only print as many characters as fit in the _current size of the terminal_. It doesn't wrap and it doesn't extend beyond the range of the terminal. So it only looks like it works if you print fewer chars than the size of your terminal. However, if you redirect the output to a file, it doesn't work at all since what you get is the control sequence and not the actual `@` character repeated.

Comment: Neither of you have done what I said about checking terminfo.  Check terminfo, as the answer says.  [The terminfo entry for Terminator](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-terminator) states no `rep` capability,  The [entry for Windows Terminal](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-ms-terminal) (for example) _does_, in contrast.  [Windows Terminal has a 16-bit limit on the number of characters printed.](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5160)  and wraps just like XTerm and others do.

Comment: This answer fails (prints only one line) in **gnome-terminal, LXTerminal, screen, MateTerminal, xfce4-terminal, terminator, tilda, and guake** (at-least) in a debian based system. It seems to only work in xterm, tmux and yakuake. That makes it quite probable that it will fail.

Comment: And, it actually doesn't **repeat a character N times** (as asked by the OP). It generates a command to be interpreted by a limited set of terminals to **present** some characters. It is akin to the presentation layer used in other systems, It doesn't try to make an string of repeated characters (what was asked) but to generate a command that might work or not depending on the terminal used.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to the original post - of over a year ago:

> repeating a character using printf and appending a newline at the end

```
printf '@%.0s' $(seq 1 $N); echo
```

Just in case someone else has the same or similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But you read carefully, the question asks if it is possible to achieve that using a single "printf" which implicitly implies echo is excluded as well

Answer (score 0):

A version that will print as many as you want (no shell line size limit triggered if you have, say, 1000000 numbers to print):

```
seq 1 $n |  xargs printf '@%.0s'   
printf '\n'
```

*note*: if you add -p to xargs (xargs -p ...) : it prompts each time it wants to launch the command, thus it shows that it crams as many args after the printf as it can, thus it launches just a few printfs in total, not 1 per arg! (that's the whole goal of xargs)

if you just wanted to generate an arbitrary long string of @:

```
yes "@" | head -n "$n" | tr -d '\n'
printf '\n'
```

just invokes yes and tr once, and should be quite fast

Comment: please explain the downvote?... (I am typing while commuting : does this fail to print n @ ? maybe the first one can t find printf and needs a : `bash -c "printf '@%.0s'"` ?)

Comment: The question asks "Is it possible to achieve the same result with a single printf (adding a newline character at the end of the output) without using sed?" Your answer is even "worse" than the version in the question, in terms of efficiency and processes launched, since you are adding yet _another_ `printf` call in the first solution and are using completely different tools in the second. So you are increasing the complexity while not actually improving anything. Unless I am missing something, which is entirely possible, I would guess that's why you were downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

One `printf`, ends in newline, variable size, works in dash, ksh, bash and zsh:

```
$ printf '%*.0s\n' 33 "" | tr " " "@"
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
$ N=20
$ printf '%.*s\n' $N '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Rather than using `printf` to generate the string, use its precision specifier to limit the length of a pre-defined pattern buffer.

The only requirement is that `$N` is less than or equal to the length of the pattern buffer. You could either use a sufficiently long pattern buffer to cover your normal use cases, or you could run-time generate the pattern buffer to account for larger values of N.